# Downconverting real signal to IQ baseband

Tags: filters, filter-design, lowpass-filter, demodulation, baseband

Despite reading various answers on this site and on other sites I am still confused about how to convert a real-valued signal back down to its original IQ baseband values. Note I am still a beginner at this.

I have a *very minimal* prototype in Matlab but I'm getting stuck. I begin by generating some IQ data and modulating it onto a carrier signal, ready to be sent as a stream of real valued numbers.

```
% constants
f = 100; % carrier frequency
Fs=500; % sampling frequency
t=(1/Fs:1000)*T; % time domain

% generate 1000 raw I/Q values to *transmit*
I=randi([0 1],1000,1)';
Q=randi([0 1],1000,1)';

% modulate I/Q values onto a carrier wave
Iwave = I.*cos(2*pi*f*t);
Qwave = Q.*sin(2*pi*f*t);
```

I assume that adding the two waves together is correct (and not subtracting them like I've seen in some notations)

```
% add up I/Q. and transmit this stream of real-valued numbers
tx=Iwave+Qwave;
```

Now the receiver mixes the signals with cos and sin waves

```
rxI = tx .* (cos(2*pi*f*t));
rxQ = tx .* (sin(2*pi*f*t));
```

Below is an FFT of the received real-valued signal in black peaking at 100Hz. And the mixed I and Q signals on the receiver, peaking at 200Hz (I know the red peak is hard to see, but it's there at 200Hz).

[image]

Now comes the tricky part. Every resource I've read mentions I should low pass filter this I and Q, and I'll be able to get back my baseband data.

```
cutoff=200/Fs;
order=32;

% a 32 order low-pass FIR filter with cutoff at 200Hz
filter=fir1(order,cutoff);

filtI=filter(filter,1,rxI);
filtQ=filter(filter,1,rxQ);
```

Here's the FFT of the I and Q signals after low-pass filtering
[image]
Now the sent and received I channel as shown below obviously look nothing alike and simply cannot be demodulated.
[image]

What am I doing wrong here?
The ideal answer would specify *exactly* what filter I need to get back my baseband data in Matlab. This I think is reasonable since the example I provided is ideal and simple.

Please also correct any misunderstandings in this post aside from the obviously incorrect filter I am using.

Comment: Try with a less ugly signal as original. Randi is a really bad choice - take a pencil, sketch its spectrum. Shift that spectrum. Shift it back. Low-pass filter the result. Is it the same spectrum? Note that you need to bandlimit your signals to a bandwidth much smaller than the carrier frequency before mixing.

Comment: Can you provide a concrete example or refer me to a resource with a concrete example, and not just general advice/equations? A concrete example speaks a 1000 words. I ultimately want to transmit random bits. Presumably it is possible to transmit random bits. How would I make this work?

Comment: As I said, your baseband signal needs to be band-limited. Yours isn't. Change that.

Comment: The example you're looking for is really the drawing I asked you to make - when you make that drawing, you should see multiple ways of solving your problem. You must take care when drawing a discrete signal's spectrum - they are periodic!

Comment: As I said, I am a beginner, it would be much more illustrative if you could explain in greater detail or with code how to band-limit baseband signals, and what shift you're referring to exactly. I asked this question for an expert to sketch out an example, if I knew how to do that I would have done that already.

Answer (score 1):

The allowed bandwidth of the data created and used to modulate the IQ signal needs to be below the cutoff frequency of the receiver post-heterodyne low pass filter, which needs to be below the carrier frequency, which needs to be below half the HF sampling rate to avoid aliasing.

So try a lower data rate and/or a much higher frequency carrier, with a suitably corresponding higher frequency sample rate.  You can lower your data rate by using a slower changing rand statement, and filtering that to remove harmonics of the squarish pulses.

Comment: Baseband data (0,1 bits) does not have a frequency associated with it. Can you explain how I would generate an IQ signal of a particular bandwidth? Something in Matlab or something concrete is preferable.

Comment: If you send 1000 bits of data (your 0,1 bits array) in 2 seconds, your data rate or frequency is 500 bits per second. You seem to be sending too many bits spread over too short a time span for your given carrier frequency and filter cut-off. Try spreading out less bits over a longer time interval of modulation.  Or use a higher carrier frequency.  You might also want to first low-pass filter the waveform of your (0,1 bits) data.